# Are boost interprocess containers suitable for thread shared storage in the same process?

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, containers

I need a vector container to be shared between two threads of the same process, providing mutex protected access for the following methods:

```
empty
size
erase
push_back
```

I would also like the collection to provide an iterator which locks the container while the iterator is in use. Essentially I am looking for a collection with a `std::vector<...>` interface but with concurrent access protection but I can't seem to find anything.

Are the `boost::interprocess` containers suitable for this application? If not, is there an alternative which is more suitable or do I have to write my own?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is yes - it is suitable. [See here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/doc/html/interprocess/some_basic_explanations.html#interprocess.some_basic_explanations.processes_and_threads)

Comment: Thanks, i see the first paragraph says "Boost.Interprocess does not work only with processes but also with threads." I had been reading the documentation here (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/doc/html/interprocess/allocators_containers.html) which seems more concerned with shared memory.

Answer (score 1):

If `boost::interprocess` containers don't work out, it may be worth looking into [Intel TBB](http://threadingbuildingblocks.org/documentation.php).  I've started using it recently and have been very pleased.  Specifically, check out `tbb::concurrent_vector`.